# Zend Gdata Youtube длина Description

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

Приветствую, проблема в том что `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry` - `getVideoDescription()` возвращает обрезанное описание видео, есть ли в `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry` метод или переменная которая вернет полное описание?

Answer (score 1):

[Это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155029/getting-title-and-description-of-embedded-youtube-video) не то?